# If $f \in S(\mathbb R)$, can we say $\widehat{|f|} \in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

Let $f\in L^{1} (\mathbb R) := \{f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C  \ \text {measurable functions} : \int_{\mathbb R} | f(x)| dx < \infty \}$ and the Fourier transform of $f$,
$\hat{f} (y) : = \int _ {\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-2\pi i x\cdot y} dx ; y \in \mathbb R $  and  $\widehat{|f|} (y) : = \int _ {\mathbb R} |f(x)| e^{-2\pi i x\cdot y} dx ; y \in \mathbb R .$

The Schwartz space, $S(\mathbb R): = \{f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R): \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |x^{\alpha} D^{\beta}f(x)|< \infty , \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\} \}$.

Theorem: The Fourier transform is a linear isomorphism  $F:S(\mathbb R)\rightarrow S(\mathbb R) \ni f\mapsto \hat {f}$.

My Question is:
Let $f\in S(\mathbb R).$

Can we expect $\widehat{|f|} \in L^{1} (\mathbb R)$  ;

Or, we can produce counter example ?

---

Thanks to math fraternity;-\ D )

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathcal F$ is a bijection on $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n) \subset L^p(\mathbb R^n) \qquad \forall\ p\in[1,\infty]$, the fourier transform of $f$ will always be in any $L^p$.

Comment: The question asks wether the Fourier transform of $|f|$ is in $L^1$. Note that in general $|f|\not\in\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Thanks for pointing that out, I simply overlooked it. I still expect it to hold, though, since $|f|\in L^1$ and, I believe, $\mathcal F : L^p \to L^{p'}$ for conjugate $p, p'$ such as $p=1, p'=\infty$ - not sure though, I don't remember the constraints on $p$ in this theorem.